# I never want the phone to go to the " lower power mode" even if the phone battery drops to 10 % .

Tags: ios

I entered low power mode on my iDevice and the battery level indicator turned yellow. Now I've plugged it in and it's up past 23% and the battery is still yellow. Does that mean I'm in Low Power Mode still? How do I get out of Low Power Mode? Update: It's at 55% and it's still yellow.

Also, let's say I enter Low Power Mode accidentally, it pops up that alert dialog awfully fast sometimes. If I entered low power mode on accident but don't want to be in it how do I exit out of it then?

Comment: If you leave the iPhone charging with the Low Power Mode enabled, it will automatically disable it when it reaches a sustainable level of battery. Around 85% I think but I'm not sure though.

Comment: Ok thanks dorito. I'll plug it in and monitor it's progress.

Comment: As corrected by @jroschen, "Low Power Mode will automatically turn off at 80%"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Go to Settings -> Battery -> Disable Low Power Mode

[image]

Low Power Mode will also turn off automatically once your device has been charged up to 80%.

Comment: @jaepage if you have an iPhone 6S/6S+ you can do a force touch on the Settings icon and you'll have a battery quick action that will take right into Battery settings. That's the fastest way as of today I guess

Answer (score 12):

You can also use Siri to turn Low Power Mode on and off.

[image]

Comment: But what happens if battery is 51% as in picture - it still looks like it is in Low Power mode. The question is how to get it out of that mode

Comment: @Mark One can just use Siri to turn it off, as well.

Answer (score -3):

Settings- Battery - slide bar to turn it off

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Answer (score -4):

Settings- Battery - Low Power Mode

Comment: How does this differ from any of the other down voted answers ?

Answer (score -5):

Settings, battery, low power mode, off

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed.